# list indices must be integers or slices, not str python3.6

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-3.6, boto3

I have a `python` script that pulls all of the `EC2` instance ids and tags in all of the AWS accounts I own. I am trying to parse for only one value of one key. Specifically I only want to parse the `Value` of the `Key` `email` from the response, but I am getting the error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Below is my code and the `json` response.

`Code:`

```
import boto3
import json

conn = boto3.resource('ec2', 
aws_access_key_id=access_key,
aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
aws_session_token=session_token)

instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running']}])

for instance in instances:
    host_list = instance.id
    host_tags = instance.tags
    print(host_tags['Key']['email']['Value'])
```

`Sample JSON:`

```
[{
    'Key': 'gitlab',
    'Value': 'true'
  }, {
    'Key': 'portfolio',
    'Value': 'xxx'
  }, {
    'Key': 'runner-manager-name',
    'Value': 'xxxxxx'
  }, ...
]
```

`Error:`

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Try: email = [tag['Value'] for tag in host_tags if tag['Key'] == 'email'][0]

Comment: Since it's complaining about `host_tags[][][]`, print out `host_tags` to see what format it's in. If it is, as I suspect, `[{'Key': 'gitlab', 'Value': 'true'}, ...`, then `host_tags['Key']` is meaningless.

Comment: Because your json structure looks like this `[ { }, ...]`.  This indicate the data is begin with list i.e. `[ ]` (so it expect number index), then only the value inside is a dictionary, which your dictionary key index is used here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the lines:

```
host_tags = instance.tags
print(host_tags['Key']['email']['Value'])
```

Rewrite it like this:

```
host_tags = instance.tags
for tag in host_tags:
    print('Key: ' + tag['Key'] + ' Value: ' + tag['Value'])
```

`instance.tags` is an array of dict. You need to process each item (tag) in the array. Then you need to process the dict extracting its key / value pairs.

Comment: The logic makes sense. I was able to get it to work.